# Why Okular (Flat Package) set external screen brightness to %100?

Tags: kde, brightness

Okular (Flat Package) set screen brightness to %100 on the first start and some other times. Setting brightness to lower values everytime is annoying. I use external monitor with HDMI and don't use laptop internal monitor.

There is no problem in "deb" or "snap" pacakge.

Some other Experiments: If select Okular from menu, there is no problem. If i use Zotero (a referance and file management application), open PDFs from Zotero with Okular, this trigger the problem.

New experiment: There is a problem in deb or snap packages too if open PDF from Zotero.

Okular Version: 1.11.2
Ubuntu Version 20.04 LTS

Comment: Kindly [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1290444/edit) the question and mention whether the `apt` version of Okular has the same issue.

Comment: I am trying now thank you.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I realized i use flatpak version of package, sorry for misunderstanding. I tried with Snap and Deb and there is no problem.

Comment: I want to try with other flatpaks.

Comment: Unless you need the very latest version for a specific reason, it may be a good idea to stick to the apt(deb) version. Sure, snap and flatpak come handy for packages that are not available in the repositories, or when the latest version is needed. However, the deb version of Okular consumes less space, less bandwidth to download, and also launches faster

Comment: Yes you are right, but i tried other packages and they are same problem too. I think problem is the Zotero.